# Where can I visualize the fonts provided with Unbuntu distribution before installing them?

Tags: fonts

Well pretty much everything is in the title.
I would like to visualize the fonts provided in the packages of the Ubuntu distribution without installing them.
Is this available, maybe somewhere on the web (couldn't find it) ?

Comment: Does [this reference](https://linuxhint.com/best_fonts_ubuntu_linux/) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks … but not really. I mean there are about 500 fonts-* and ttf-* available packages reported by apt. 155 are currently installed on my system, so before browsing hundred of thousands fonts on the web, I would like to see what is already there but not installed.